# In below code which is compared in Arrays?(length/type) JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object

````
let numbers = new Array(1,2,3);
let numbers2 = new Array(1,2,3);
let alphabet = new Array("a","b","c");
let secondSet = new Array("a","b","c");
console.log(typeof(numbers))
console.log(typeof(secondSet))
console.log(numbers === numbers2);
console.log(numbers === alphabet);
console.log(secondSet == alphabet);```
````

***can it is true in any case? how it is compared??****

Comment: `JSON.stringify(array1) === JSON.stringify(array2)`

Comment: can you use `JSON.stringify` in your environment?

Comment: @prudvirufus why did you unaccept my answer? Can I help you

Answer (score 0):

Comparing arrays can be done by (suggested in the comments) converting the array (object) to a string, using `JSON.stringify()` and comparing the two strings:

```js
let numbers = new Array(1,2,3);
let numbers2 = new Array(1,2,3);

console.log(JSON.stringify(numbers) === JSON.stringify(numbers2));
```

Or you could loop through the elements of the array using `Array.prototype.every()` for example in this way:

```js
let numbers = new Array(1,2,3);
let numbers2 = new Array(1,2,3);

const isequal = numbers.length === numbers2.length && numbers.every((value, i) => value === numbers2[i]);
console.log(isequal);
```

In most cases, the first option will do the job.